# Input random letter to textbox in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have problem with inputting random letter in textbox. Here's code:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Timers

Public Class Form1
Dim SlovaTimer As Timer
Dim AbecedaArray() As Char = {"A", "B", "C", "Č", "Ć", "D", "Dž", "Đ", "E", "F", "G", "H" _
                             , "I", "J", "K", "L", "Lj", "M", "N", "Nj", "O", "P", "R" _
                             , "S", "Š", "T", "U", "V", "Z", "Ž"}
Dim counter As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SlovaTimer = New Timer(200)
    AddHandler SlovaTimer.Elapsed, New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf Handler)
    SlovaTimer.Enabled = True
    Button1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Handler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    If counter = 11 Then
        SlovaTimer.Stop()
        Button2.Enabled = False
    Else
        Dim ctrl As Control
        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(TextBox)) Then
                Dim txt As TextBox = CType(ctrl, TextBox)
                If txt.Tag = counter Then
                    Dim random As New Random
                    Dim randletter As Integer = random.Next(0, 29)
                    Dim letter As String
                    letter = AbecedaArray(randletter)
                    txt.Text = letter
                End If
            End If
        Next
        SlovaTimer.Start()
    End If
```

Here's error: **Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.** Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead - or drag one from the toolbox onto the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you are trying to change the text of a Textbox in a thread that is not the UI thread.

In this case, you can replace the `System.Timers.Timer` with `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` as [Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix) suggested in his comment, and this will probably solve the problem.

However, you should know how to handle these exceptions if you come across them in the future.

To make a cross-thread call to a UI control in winforms you need to use `Invoke`. 
Create a method for setting the text of a textbox, and a delegate to that method:

```
Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(txt as TextBox, newString As String)

Private Sub SetText(txt as TextBox, newString As String)

    ' Calling from another thread? -> Use delegate
    If txt.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        ' Execute delegate in the UI thread, pass args as an array
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {txt, newString})
    Else ' Same thread, assign string to the textbox
        txt.Text = newString
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, as you can see, this method actually invokes itself if the property `InvokeRequired` of the `textbox` returns `True`. if it returns `False`, it means that you can safely set the `Text` of the textbox.

Comment: Thank you. Did a little research on the internet, so it's clear now. Thank you Zohar Peled, you helped me alot! :)

Comment: If an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know the problem is solved.